# Discrepancy Between Generated and Received Throughput in VoIP Simulation with OMNeT++ and simu5G

Tags: voip, omnet++, inet

I am having an issue with my OMNeT simulation results while using OMNeT++ 5.6.2, inet 4.2.2, and simu5G 1.1.0.

I have tried various VoIP configurations, but the outcome remains consistent: the generated throughput is lower than the received throughput. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGiOh.png)

Also, when I was trying to build the project, I ran into some errors. I'm not quite sure if these errors have anything to do with the throughput difference. I'd appreciate some guidance on how to fix these issues. Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J9W9.png)

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide [mcve]? And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is. This is the code for VoIPSender (generated throughput). `void VoIPSender::initialize(int stage)
{
    EV << "VoIP Sender initialize: stage " << stage << endl;

    cSimpleModule::initialize(stage);

    // avoid multiple initializations
    if (stage!=inet::INITSTAGE_APPLICATION_LAYER)
        return;

    durTalk_ = 0;
    durSil_ = 0;
    selfSource_ = new cMessage("selfSource");
    scaleTalk_ = par("scale_talk");
    shapeTalk_ = par("shape_talk");
    scaleSil_ = par("scale_sil");
    shapeSil_ = par("shape_sil");`

Comment: `isTalk_ = par("is_talk");
    iDtalk_ = 0;
    nframes_ = 0;
    nframesTmp_ = 0;
    iDframe_ = 0;
    timestamp_ = 0;
    size_ = par("PacketSize");
    sampling_time = par("sampling_time");
    selfSender_ = new cMessage("selfSender");
    localPort_ = par("localPort");
    destPort_ = par("destPort");
    silences_ = par("silences");

    totalSentBytes_ = 0;
    warmUpPer_ = getSimulation()->getWarmupPeriod();
    voIPGeneratedThroughtput_ = registerSignal("voIPGeneratedThroughput");

    initTraffic_ = new cMessage("initTraffic");
    initTraffic();
}`

Comment: `// emit throughput sample
    totalSentBytes_ += size_;
    double interval = SIMTIME_DBL(simTime() - warmUpPer_);
    if (interval > 0.0)
    {
        double tputSample = (double)totalSentBytes_ / interval;
        emit(voIPGeneratedThroughtput_, tputSample );
    }

    if (nframesTmp_ > 0)
        scheduleAt(simTime() + sampling_time, selfSender_);
}`

Comment: this is the original code from SIMU5G

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76849384/edit) the question and add that code into the question? Moreover, could you insert error as a text?

Comment: @IzzatiT. do you have two independent apps for the sender? That could be the issue. Your `server` sends frames from `app[1]`, while you `UE` receives them at `app[0]`. Maybe you've misplaced them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a difference between how voipsender calculates throughput and how voipreceiver calculates it.
If you print totalRcvdBytes_ in voipReceiver, you will notice that it's in bits meaning the values are(320, 640, 960, ...) but if you print totalSentBytes_ in voipsender, it is in bytes meaning the values are (40, 80, ...). That's why the throughput in voipreceiver is always higher.